# A function to remove specified elements

Tags: javascript, html

I need to create a function which gets user input (a css selector) and removes all of those elements.
This is the function so far

```
function removeBySelector(selector) {
  var thisOne = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
  for(var i = 0; i<thisOne.length; i++) {
    document.removeChild(thisOne[0]);
  };
};
```

and the HTML that starts it

```
<button type="button" name="button" onclick="removeBySelector(prompt('Type the selector e.g p/ p.pClass'));">Remove By Selector</button>
```

Comment: Try `thisOne[i].parentNode.removeChild(thisOne[i]);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your method to

```
function removeBySelector(selector) 
{
  var thisOne = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
  for(var i = 0; i<thisOne.length; i++) 
  {
    thisOne[i].parentNode.removeChild( thisOne[i] ); //changed parentElement to parentNode
  };
}
```

Comment: @RayonDabre yes spotted it maybe 10 seconds before you posted your comment :)

Comment: you can use `thisOne[i].remove()` everywhere but internet explorer ... fortunately there's a [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/remove#Polyfill) so you can use that easier to read code everywhere

Comment: @JaromandaX, People will get more confused if they find `remove()` in Native js code. :P

Comment: The above method didn't worked, but Jaromanda X's method worked.

Comment: @RayonDabre - it's been in the DOM standard for years - microsoft do not dictate web standards

Comment: I did it with parentNode already but it doesn't work as well (

Answer (score 0):

i'd advise using the framework [jQuery](https://jquery.com/)! It is a very powerful tool that helps you simplify and improve your JavaScript code and it's performance.

With jQuery you can easily use this piece of code to remove any elements by CSS selector.

```
// Use any CSS Selector here

var elements = $(".class");

$.each(elements, function(){

$(this).remove();

)};
```

This keeps your code very easy to read and has a high performance.

Comment: Where did you find `jQuery` tag in the question ? And why jQuery ? What are the benefits of using it in this case ?

Comment: `thisOne[i].remove()` (with polyfill for IE) means no need for bloatation devices ... `has a high performance` - opinion denied

Comment: yes I know can do this easily in jQuery but need with JS

Comment: It was a advise, and thus can be done or not, i included a solution done with jQuery too, which i would like you to keep in mind first of all!

I understand why you ask how it is benificial in this particular case, it does not improve this snippet by much, but keep in mind this is probably not all of his code. jQuery has many usages, performance and compability related, and i wanted to push him in jQuery's direction, thus the **advise**

And i just saw your response Hayk, if you cannot use jQuery for whatever reasons, you can use the other answer as i see it works with the fix in the comment.

Comment: Do you want him to change all of his code for the sake of jQuery ? There are people who still prefer core JS for complex projects and if you are about to ask _why_ ? The do read about it..

Answer (score 0):

```
//Try this code:

    var removeElement=function(selector){
         $(document).find(selector).remove();
        };
     removeElement('h1'); // will remove all H1 elements from Document.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the same, without using any library with pure javascript (ES6 syntax in this case):

```js
let elements = document.querySelectorAll(".please-remove");
elements.forEach(e => e.remove());
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="keep">Keep this element</div>
  <div class="please-remove">1</div>
  <div class="please-remove">2</div>
  <div class="please-remove">3</div>
  <div class="please-remove">4</div>
  <div class="please-remove">5</div>
  <div class="please-remove">6</div>
</div>
```